# Exception while trying to move to another Activity after some delay in android

Tags: android, exception

In my android application, am trying to move from an Activity to another after a given time delay. The code of first Activity is follows :

```
package com.example.groupmessenger;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;
int secondsDelayed = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(30,90,30));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomePage.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

When I ran my app these exceptions occured :

```
08-28 12:28:09.388: W/dalvikvm(1241): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.groupmessenger/com.example.groupmessenger.HomePage}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1541)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1416)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3351)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3312)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3522)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3490)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.example.groupmessenger.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:27)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-28 12:28:09.418: E/AndroidRuntime(1241):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Am a newbie to android. So can anyone tell me how to solve this exceptions.

Comment: `have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` Did you check that?

Comment: check whether your activity mentioned in Manifest or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare Activity HomePage is AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        . . .
        <activity android:name="com.example.groupmessenger.HomePage" /> 
        . . .
</application>
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Creating) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Solution is Declare `com.example.groupmessenger.HomePage` this activity in your manifest file..

Answer (score 0):

Add your activity declaration to `AndroidManifest.xml`, see the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#Creating)

Answer (score 0):

Inside Application tag write this code

```
<activity android:name="com.example.groupmessenger.HomePage"/>
```